# Javascript returning incorrecct results

Tags: javascript

Before I start, I would like to say that if this question has already been answered please direct me to the appropriate answer.

I am having an issue with my Java Script function not returning an expected value. I am trying to use it to validate text input for a number range, and, if the input is outside that range, return a custom error message.

here is the HTML for one of the fields within a the form which I am trying to validate:

```
<td><input name="bottomair" type="text" required id="bottomair"
   size="3" onChange="bottomAirF()"></td>
<td class="noborder" id="bottomairerror"></td>
```

And here is the associated Javascript:

```
function bottomAirF() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("bottomair");
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("bottomairerror").innerHTML = text;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the function check to see if the entered number is between 33 and 40. If the number is not between these two numbers, the code should return the error message "Temp Out of Tolerance" but if the number is between 33 and 40 it should return nothing. As it stands right now, any number (or lack there of) returns the error message.

This code is modified from W3School's Comparison function.

I have tried everything that I can think of and it is still not working properly so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although all the posted answers are technically correct, I believe this solution is neither maintenable nor scalable.

You have hard dependency on element ids which are static.

Imaging if, in future, you want to add more of these `td`s that perform such validation, are you going to keep track of newly added rows?
Although, technically you can but anthropologically its mentally draining and things like this deny to make use of the very purpose the computers and software is designed - Automation.
Something that lets you do creative tasks and have the mechanical stuff done by the computer.

For this philosophical reason, I believe this piece of code is a much better solution.

HTML - Get rid of Ids and pass `this` meaning current element (which is input in this case) as a parameter to the function.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" required size="3" onChange="bottomAirF(this)"></td>
        <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS - use DOM accessors to find next `td` and update it's `innerHTML`

```
function bottomAirF(elem) {
    var x, text;
    x = +elem.value; // Prepended + sign will parse whatever follows to integer.
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }
    elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
}
```

EDIT: For the updated requirements

To add new validations and conditions.

Let's say you have 3 textboxes which you need validation on. Each of these textboxes have different validation parameters.

First Should only accept values between 1 and 10

Second should only accept values between 11 and 33

Third should only accept values between 33 and 41

So the updated code would be, (the name of the function will be changed to something generic, like, `validate`)

Notice that there are two additional attributes on the `input` element viz `val-min` and `val-max` that specify the range.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" required val-min="1" val-max="10" size="3" onChange="validate(this)"></td>
        <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" required val-min="11" val-max="33" size="3" onChange="validate(this)"></td>
        <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" required val-min="33" val-max="40" size="3" onChange="validate(this)"></td>
        <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS Code

```
function validate(elem) {
    var x, text;
    x = +elem.value; // Prepended + sign will parse whatever follows to integer.
    var min = elem.getAttribute('val-min');
    var max = elem.getAttribute('val-max')
    if (isNaN(x) || x < min || x > max) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }
    elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = text;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/sdnb87g4/16/)

Comment: With this JS code, by the sounds of your explanation, I would be able to use one function for all of the different input fields (which would need to fall within this range)? The reason I ask is because like you pointed out, right now I am having to make a new function for each input field.

Comment: Exactly, that's the whole point of this approach. Please check updated answer. :)

Comment: @AdityaParad, Thank you very much however the first set of code would work just fine for what I am trying to do. I will still have about four different functions to code but that is better then the 20+ individual functions I was looking at coding before. This answer not only solves my originally posted question but also another question that I was trying to figure out which is how to simplify the coding. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `.value`

```
x = document.getElementById("bottomair").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

please instead this line:

```
document.getElementById("bottomair");
```

write this line:

```
document.getElementById("bottomair").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
x = document.getElementById("bottomair").value;
    if (isNaN(x) || parseInt(x,10) < 33 || parseInt(x) > 40) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done very well all you needed was to add 
value to  document.getElementById("bottomair")

Here is the solution I've just added the .value

**x = document.getElementById("bottomair")**.**value**;

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Missing .value

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnCalc").click(
            function () {
                bottomAirF();
            }            
        );
    });



function bottomAirF() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("bottomair").value;

    if (isNaN(x) || x < 33 || x > 40) {
        text = "Temp Out of Tolerance";
    } else {
        text = " ";
    }

    document.getElementById("bottomairerror").innerHTML = text;
}
```

See
[Simple JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ofavfjr2/)